# HTML5 <Header><Nav> overlapping body

Tags: html, header

I am a newb to HTML5 and i can't seem to fix this problem.  You can see from the image below that the header is overlapping the content area. How can i fix this?  is it something with my header css?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIPIG.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?     family=Open+Sans:300italic,600italic,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 


<!--Stylesheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->   

<!--HTML5 video player-->
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

</head> 

<body>

<header>

    <div id="headercontainer">

        <h1><a class="introlink anchorLink" href="#intro">Test Site</a></h1>

        <nav> 
            <ul>
                <li><a class="introlink anchorLink" href="#intro">Intro</a>   </li>
                <li><a class="portfoliolink anchorLink"  href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a class="aboutlink anchorLink" href="#about">About</a> </li>
                <li><a class="contactlink anchorLink" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </nav>

    </div>

</header> 


<div id="content">
<article>
<section>

    <h1 class="article"> Lorem ipsum</h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    </section>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
body{
margin: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: small;
background-image:url('Media\background.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
padding-top::50px;      
   }

header { padding: 5px 0; width: 100%; background-color: #000; margin-bottom: 25px; 
position: fixed; z-index: 10; float: left; }
#headercontainer, #contentcontainer { width: 960px; 
margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `position: fixed;` from the header CSS.

Comment: what if the OP wants the header to be fixed? :)

Comment: Does he say something about this?

Comment: What do i have to edit to reduce the height of the black part of the header so the orange box drops below it a little bit?

Comment: The height of the black header is calculated by the height of the "yellow box" and the padding from the header-tag. To reduce the height you have to put the yellow box, the <h1>, outside of the header-tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the fixed position of the header, then you need to apply `margin-top` to  the body to compensate for it.

Also with fixed position of the header you don't actually need `margin-bottom` for it.

```
body {
    margin: 25px 0 0 0; /* considering that the header is 25px */
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    background-image:url('Media\background.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    padding-top: 50px;      
}
```